# open eye and closed eye in android by Android eye detection and tracking with OpenCV

Tags: java, android, opencv, face-detection, eye-tracking

i made application eye detecting by following this link [link](http://romanhosek.cz/android-eye-detection-and-tracking-with-opencv/) and it work
how can i detect the eye is opened or closed ?
is there library in android to detect closed or opened

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opencv - detecting whether the eye is closed or open](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563835/opencv-detecting-whether-the-eye-is-closed-or-open)

Comment: The new Android Face API supports detecting "eyes open" and "smiling": https://developers.google.com/vision/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've no idea whether there is any library for that, but using technique descirbed in article `Eye-blink detection system for human–computer interaction` by `Aleksandra Królak and Paweł Strumiłło` (you can download it [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10209-011-0256-6) [and here](http://paperity.org/p/8557547/eye-blink-detection-system-for-human-computer-interaction) and here is some [simplified version](http://medialt.no/pub/uikt/u2010/011-Krolak/index.html)) in my opinion is a good option. Generally this technique is quite simple:

1. Find eye (or both eyes). Remember this part of image as a template.
2. In next frame use some kind of corellation (authors used normalized cross correlation method, but you can try with other types - OpenCV [has few types of correlation methods implemented](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html#which-are-the-matching-methods-available-in-opencv)) to find region similar to your template. Place with highest correlation value (most likely) will be eye.
3. If correlation value > some_threshold_value than eye is open, otherwise it is closed.

Threshold value used by authors is in the article, but when i was using this technique i've used other value so most likely you will need to find value for your case on your own.